# Doxygen fails to recognize parameters with using namespace

Tags: c++, doxygen

I've the following header file:

```cpp
#ifndef DATA_EXCEPTION_HPP_
#define DATA_EXCEPTION_HPP_

#include "Data/Global.hpp"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

namespace Data {

class DATA_LIB Exception : public std::exception {
public:

  Exception(const std::string& message);
  virtual ~Exception() = default;

public:

  const char* what() const override;

private:

  std::string m_message;
};

} // namespace Data

#endif // !DATA_EXCEPTION_HPP_

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DOCUMENTATION                                                             //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * @class Data::Exception
 *
 * @brief Basic exception for Data
 *
 * This is the base exception that can be thrown by elements present in the
 * project.
 */
```

And following source file

```cpp
#include "Data/Exception.hpp"

namespace Data {

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// USING SECTION                                                             //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using std::string;
using std::exception;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PUBLIC SECTION                                                            //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Exception::Exception(const string& message) :
exception(),
m_message(message) {

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// VIRTUAL PUBLIC SECTION                                                    //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const char* Exception::what() const {
  return m_message.c_str();
}

} // namespace Data
```

This is the error message of doxygen:

```
M:/XXX/Exception.cpp:16: error: no matching class member found for
  Data::Exception::Exception(const string &message)
Possible candidates:
  Data::Exception::Exception(const std::string &message)
  FilesystemRepository::Exception::Exception(const std::string &message)
 (warning treated as error, aborting now)
```

This is a warning, not an error, but since I've enabled the option for considering all warning as error I've this.

I can disable the warning as error flag, but my opinion is that this should not be a warning, since it's perfectly valid C++ code so doxygen should be able to check that the `string` in the .cpp file is the `std::string` due to the `using std::string`.

Is there a way to remove the warning by maintain the same code? Because I'm doing the same thing with longer namespaces and it will be cumbersome to use fill namespace in arguments every time.

EDIT:

I'm using doxygen version 1.8.14 on Windows10 64 bit.

This is my doxyfile:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "CGF"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = @CGF_VERSION@
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "Computer Generated Forces simulation."
# PROJECT_LOGO           = logo.svg
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = @DOC_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = YES
ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = YES
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO
STRIP_FROM_PATH        =
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    =
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 2
ALIASES                =
TCL_SUBST              =
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      =
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 3
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
GROUP_NESTED_COMPOUNDS = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       =
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    =
LAYOUT_FILE            =
CITE_BIB_FILES         =

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
WARN_AS_ERROR          = YES
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           =

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

INPUT                  = @CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR@/src @CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR@/doc/doxygen
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.inl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = @CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR@/src/Stub
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       =
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        =
EXAMPLE_PATH           =
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = YES
IMAGE_PATH             = @CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR@/doc/doxygen/images
INPUT_FILTER           =
FILTER_PATTERNS        =
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS =
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE =

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

SOURCE_BROWSER                  = NO
INLINE_SOURCES                  = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS             = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION          = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION             = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE          = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS                 = YES
USE_HTAGS                       = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS                = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING          = NO
CLANG_OPTIONS                   =
CLANG_COMPILATION_DATABASE_PATH = 0

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          =

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = @CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@/d_header.html
HTML_FOOTER            = @CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@/d_footer.html
HTML_STYLESHEET        =
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = @CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@/d_stylesheet.css
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       =
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = NO
HTML_DYNAMIC_MENUS     = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = YES
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "CGF Documentation"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = it.log-in.cgf
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = it.log-in.cgf
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Log.In S.r.l.
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               =
HHC_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     =
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               =
QHP_NAMESPACE          = it.log-in.cgf
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   =
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  =
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  =
QHG_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = it.log-in.cgf
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = YES
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     =
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       =
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       =
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     =
EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  =

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         =
LATEX_HEADER           =
LATEX_FOOTER           =
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET =
LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      =
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
LATEX_TIMESTAMP        = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    =
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    =
RTF_SOURCE_CODE        = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_SUBDIR             =
MAN_LINKS              = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the DOCBOOK output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
DOCBOOK_PROGRAMLISTING = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX =

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           =
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  =
PREDEFINED             =
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TAGFILES               =
GENERATE_TAGFILE       =
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
MSCGEN_PATH            =
DIA_PATH               =
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           =
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = svg
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = YES
DOT_PATH               =
DOTFILE_DIRS           =
MSCFILE_DIRS           =
DIAFILE_DIRS           =
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      =
PLANTUML_CFG_FILE      =
PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  =
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

There's some `@variable@` stuff because I'm using it with CMake for retrieving come information.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Any settings in your doxygen configuration file that differ from the default doxygen configuration file (except for the setting warning as error)? Please add this information to the question. With the 1.8.16 version and the default configuration file I could not reproduce the problem when adding a FilesystemRepository.hpp with a similar contents as Exception.cpp (just another namespace name) I could reproduce the problem. Best is to file an issue report at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new with attached a, small, self contained example.

Comment: I've edited the post for adding those information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default configuration file I could not reproduce the problem when adding a FilesystemRepository.hpp with a similar contents as Exception.cpp (just another namespace name) I could reproduce the problem.

In the default configuration file as well as in the file used by OP `BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT=NO`.

As far as I can see the solution is setting: `BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT=YES`

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue, even if I don't understand the meaning of the parameter and why it gives the error, even after reading its description...